# Does Hyperledger fabric use CouchDB internally and if yes how can we access it directly ? and In fabric does channel somewhat means network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Does Hyperledger fabric use CouchDB internally and if yes how can we access it directly ?
and
In fabric does channel somewhat means network???

Answer (score 2):

Fabric supports two databases to store state:  goleveldb (embedded, default) and CouchDB.  The choice of state database is is determined via the configuration settings for the peer ( https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L551-L586 ).  It all depends on your setup, but the default CouchDB listen port is 5984.  Take a look at the CouchDB v2.1.x documentation for how to access directly via a UI or the native CouchAPIs.